# Jenkins with Parallel Builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, parallel-builds, ninja

I have a small Jenkins VM running for our shop, keep it's ever-watchful eye on about a dozen github projects.  It's currently configured with 3 executors (it's only a 4-cpu VM), and chugs along happily.

However, 2 of these projects are very big (90-minute compile & test cycle).  On workstations, we typically use "make -j6" or Ninja to speed it up, and it does so GREATLY.  I'ld like to do this on Jenkins, but I can't find a way to make a single job consume multiple executors.

What I'ld like is to be able to configure a number of Executors to allocate to a job, so that I don't have both of these monster jobs running at the same time, but still leave all the other smaller jobs with a single-executor each so that they can run in parallel.

Any ideas?

Comment: there are plugins to prevent two jobs from running at the same time. One of them, is the locks & latches plugin and the other on is the critical section plugin.

Comment: I looked at those, but I'ld really like a bit more flexibility.. Eventually I forsee having a bigger VM or more jobs and I'ld like the ability to have some jobs only consume half of the executors, and leave the rest open for tiny jobs.  Simply restricting "don't run A and B" at the same time doesn't seem enough, I need something like "don't run A unless there are >3 open executors, and then mark them all busy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the [Jenkins Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) for you and found the [Heavy Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin). Exactly what you want